# How can I cache and reload docker images in GitHub Actions?

Tags: docker, github

We use our own images to build our code in GitHub Actions. It works great. But the problem is that we need to constantly download our images for each build and our images are large in size (some more than 2 GBs).

I saw GitHub's default example for cache action. Yet I can't figure out how can I change it to save and load a docker image. I know I can use docker save image_name > some_file and docker load < some_file. But I can't merge that with GitHub Action syntax. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the github caching mechanism to cache docker images, `actions/cache` action and include docker image layers.

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ...

    steps:
      - name: checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: cache docker layers
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: |
            |2
            /path/to/docker/image  
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-docker-${{ hashFiles('/path/to/docker/image') }}

      - name: load from cache
        run: docker load -i /path/to/docker/image/my_image.tar
```

Comment: can you also show me how can I cache it?